# Why cant servers be recognized in Azure Logic Apps?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have created a Logic App and set a Sliding Window. I have added the next step as Execute a SQL Query (V2)  but if i put the server name in there it gives an error

```
Could not retrieve values. Error code: '400', Message: 'Invalid connection settings inner exception: 
Key 
'token' in connection profile is not valid. inner exception: Unexpected character encountered while 
parsing value: h. Path '', line 0, position 0. clientRequestId: ????
```

Comment: or is there a better way in Azure to schedule running a sql statement on an Azure DB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set admin for your sql server with service principal, it may show this error message. You can create a group and add the service principal or ad users into a group. And then set sql admin for the group.

Here is a similar [post](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Azure-SQL-with-Azure-AD-authentication-dose-not-work/td-p/458138) which may help you.